# Overwriting object instance does not release memory?

Tags: python, class, garbage-collection, circular-reference

I have a python object which is essentially a collection of other object instances. You can append other objects to it (which it just stores in a list). It is created when reading a file, eg:

```
def file_reader(file):
    obj = MyCollection()

    for line in file:
        other_obj = line_reader(line)
        obj.append(other_obj)
    return obj
```

If I then try to overwrite the object later (by reading a different file), the original data is not deleted, the object is just extended. Strangely, this seems to happen if I use different references:

```
obj1 = file_reader(file)
obj2 = file_reader(file1)
```

I suspect I have some kind of problem with circular referencing, but I can't quite grasp the logic. 
Anyone have an idea?

Edit:
The essential part of MyCollection looks like:

```
class MyCollection(object):

    def __init__(self, objs = []):
        self.objs = objs

   def append(self, obj):
        self.objs.append(obj)
```

Comment: Could you show the code for `MyCollection()`? I'm betting the list is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Comment: Could you provide us, please, with the code of `MyCollection` object? It could be helpful.

Comment: edited the question to add the collection class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll take a not-so-wild guess that you currently have something like this:

```
class MyCollection():
    listOfThings = []
    def __init__(self):
```

In this case, `listOfThings` is a *class attribute*, it is shared amongst all instances of the `MyCollection` class. Instead, you want an *instance attribute*, separate for each instance:

```
class MyCollection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.listOfThings = []
```

---

**Edit**: so close!

The issue you have is in:

```
def __init__(self, objs = []):
```

Here, `objs` is known as a "mutable default parameter". The list in the default parameter values is shared for all instances of that class that *don't* pass anything to `__init__` (defining `a = MyCollection([])`, for instance, would create a new instance with a separate `objs` list).

You should use:

```
def __init__(self, objs=None):
    if objs is None:
        objs = []
```

Canonical question covering this: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to look up 'mutable default parameter', and presto, my exact example is in the guide: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: BTW, list is not used as the actual class is a fair bit bigger with other methods. You hit the problem though :)

Comment: Yes, this is a classic example of something that is incredibly easy to find information on, but only if you already know what it's called!